# Play h.264 video stream in html page

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, vlc

I am using **ffmpeg** and **vlc** on linux to produce MPEG transport stream (`mpegts`) over HTTP. Basically `ffmpeg` captures the screen and produces `h.264` stream using `mpegts` and then `vlc` is used as a server that delivers the stream over `http`. That's how I manage to accomplish this.

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1280x800 -r 30 -i :0.0+0,0  -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -s 1280x800 -threads 0 -f mpegts - | vlc -I dummy - --sout '#std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:3030}
```

And some useful log about the resulting stream:

```
Output #0, mpegts, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.72.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv444p(progressive), 1280x800, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.96.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.96.101 mp2
```

All looks good except for that I am unable to play the stream in a HTML page. Could someone point me at some solution to either render the stream in HTML page or change the stream type so that it gets rendered. 
Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
I've noticed something weird. The `<video>` fails to play mp4 files on Firefox (51.0.1) for Ubuntu (I have also tested on Windows 8 with Chrome).
I simply use `ffmpeg` to record screen for 10 seconds and produce .mp4 video (see below).

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1280x800 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -t 00:00:10 ~/Workspace/videostream/output.mp4
```

And then play the *output.mp4* video with the following snippet.

```
<video width="480" height="320" controls="controls">
    <source src="output.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This simply does not play although I can open the video with any other media player. The media info (using MediaInfo, v0.7.96) of the `output.mp4` file is:

```
GENERAL: MPEG-4 (Base Media): 1.007 MiB, 10s 0ms; 1 Video stream: AVC; Overall bit rate: 825 Kbps; Writing application: Lavf57.72.101
VIDEO: 2 343 Kbps, 1280*800(16:10), at 25.000 fps, MPEG Video (Version 2) (Main@High 1440)
```

However, if I replace the `output.mp4` with any other `.mp4` file, it does play in Firefox. So, this leads me to conclude that it is not a browser issue but something with the way I exploit `ffmpeg`. Below is the media info of a proper `.mp4` file that successfully runs in the browser.

```
GENERAL: MPEG-4 (Base Media/Version 2): 48.4 MiB, 2mn 50s; 1 Video stream: AVC; 1 Audio stream: AAC; Overall bit mode rate: Variable; Overall bit rate: 2 385 Kbps;
VIDEO: 2 256 Kbps, 1280*720(16:9), at 25.000 fps, AVC (Main@L3.1) (CABAC / 3 Ref Frames); ISO media produced by Google Inc.
AUDIO:
126 Kbps, 44.1 KHz, 2 channels, AAC (LC), ISO media produced by Google Inc.
```

And here is the media info of the output file that results from redirecting the h.264 mpegts stream using the `ffmpeg` command with **-pix_fmt yuv420p** `./ffmpeg -t 00:00:10 -f x11grab -s 1280x800 -r 30 -i :0.0+0,0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -s 1280x800 -threads 0 -f mpegts - > ~/Workspace/file.ts`:

```
GENERAL: MPEG-TS: 2.93 MiB, 9s 960ms; 1 Video stream: MPEG Video; 1 Menu stream: MPEG Video; Overall bit rate mode: Variable; Overall bit rate: 2 465 Kbps; 
VIDEO: 2 343 Kbps, 1280*800(16:10), at 25.000 fps, MPEG Video (Version 2) (Main@High 1440)
```

Comment: Use WebM/MKV, and it should play just fine in a `<video>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think **yuv444p** is playable in the `<video>` tag by any browser.

You probably need an **ffmpeg** binary that can output the more mellow **yuv420p** planar. Maybe you can pass that as option to **libx264**, like this: `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.

**EDIT:**
Here's what worked for me:

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" screen:// :screen-fps=25 :screen-caching=5000 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,scale=1,width=800,height=600,acodec=none}:http{mux=ogg,dst=:8181/desktop} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep
```

The only downside seems to be the performance. It's slow. Maybe it's something specific to the Windows build of VLC, hopefully it does better on Linux. Also, try other codec/container combo, i have no clue if Theora is the appropriate choice for encoding a desktop capture.

Tested in Chrome (Windows) with

```html
<video controls>
    <source src="http://127.0.0.1:8181/desktop">
</video>
```

NOTE: You don't have to use localhost, VLC listens on

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8181
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I tried your suggestion but to no avail unfortunately. I'd like to note also that I have changed the part of the `vlc` command `'#std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:3030}` to `'#std{access=http,mux=mp4,dst=:3030}` but again without success. I was considering also the option for any flash player. So far I have only managed to play the stream with `application/x-vlc-plugin` which is not a good option.

Comment: Can you add the output of mediainfo file.ts and file.mp4 to the question? https://mediaarea.net/.  We need to understand what your ffmpeg binary produces.

Comment: I have updated the question post with the media info of all output files. The `ffmpeg` binary was compiled and built using the `ffmpeg` compilation guide (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). Perhaps I need to encode the video some other way or miss some important params for the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: The `video` tag displays "No video with supported format and MIME type found.".

Comment: I would drop **ffmpeg** and use **vlc** alone, they don't seem to get along very well for this scenario. See my edited answer.